# Proving that the union of compact sets is compact (in $\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

*Proof*

Let $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a collection of nonempty compact sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$

Since each $C_i$ is compact, there are finitely many open sets $O_1,O_2,...,O_m \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{j=1}^m O_j \supseteq C_i$

Since the finite union of finite sets is finite, there exists an finite subcover of $\mathcal{U}$, $\mathcal{U}_o$ such that $\mathcal{U}_o \supseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$.

Thus, $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$ is compact.  $\hspace{1cm} \square$

---

Did I leave anything out or did I make any jumps in my logic? Let me know.

Comment: What's $\mathcal U_o$?

Comment: $\mathcal{U}_o$ is the finite subcover of any open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$

Comment: I'd explicitely add and point out that:  If $\mathscr U$ is a cover of $\cup C_i$ then $\mathscr U$ is a cover for each $C_i$.  (You assumed that implicitely but I think it should be explicitely pointed out.)  And I think you should work on exactly how you will *state* that union of theses finite subcovers is a cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea looks correct, though you may want to be more careful about your indexing. Another way to state what you've done is the following.

Let $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a family of compact sets, and let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $\bigcup_{i=1}^nC_i$. Thus $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover for each $C_i$. So by compactness, each $C_i$ is covered by some $U^i_1,\ldots,U^i_{j_i}\in\mathcal{U}$. Now the collection
$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{U_1^i,\ldots,U_{j_i}^i\}\subset\mathcal{U}
$$
forms a finite subcover for $\bigcup_{i=1}^nC_i$.

Comment: I see what you mean. I like how you worded it. It's much more concise

Answer (score 2):

You are on the good tract, you just have to consider $\cup O_{i_n}^i$

where $C_i$ is a subset of the union of open subsets $O^i_{i_1},...,O^i_{i_{n_i}}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, mostly because of your formatting. May I ask what you mean by $O^i$?

Comment: it is an element of $\cal{U}$

Comment: Oh so when you say $O_{i_1}^i$, the "raising $O$ to the $i^{th}$ power" is a way of indexing $O$ a second time. $O^i$ denotes "some open set $O$ that is part of the open cover for $C_i$." Am I understanding you correctly now?

Comment: exactly this what I want to say

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is good but:

I'd explicitly point out that $\mathscr U$ being a cover of $\cup C_i$ then $\mathscr U$ is therefore a cover of each $C_i$.  (You *implicitly* assume that is clear but I think it should be deliberately noted.)

And in manipulating the finite subcover I'd be a little more exact and formal.

I'd point that for each $C_k$ we have a finite number of $_kO_{1},....,_kO_{m_k}\in \mathscr U$ that form an open subcover, $\mathscr U_k=\cup_{i=1}^{m_k} $$_kO_i$, of $C_k$.

The $\overline {\mathscr U}=\cup \mathscr U_k$ (or whatever notation you like) is a finite open cover.

(We could further state, but don't need to, that $\overline {\mathscr U}=\cup_{k=1}^n (\cup_{i=1}^{m_k} $$_kO_i)$.)

(As you currently have it written it is implicit but not actually stated how you get the $O_m$ for a *particular* $C_i$ to getting a collection of ... sets indexed how? ... for the union of all the $C_i$. It's better to be able to spell it out explicitly.)

....

Also, this is me nitpicking.... *really* nitpicking.  You should specify as *finite* union in the title of the post.  That it is a *finite* union and not an infinite union is essential.